# List animation objects in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

Is there a function in Dymola that lists all the animation objects of a simulation?

I have looked through the listfunctions() functions but did not find anything obvious there that would give this information.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is currently no such function in Dymola.

I assume you mean a function that lists all 3D-animation objects in a simulation result, possibly with type (sphere, cylinder, surface, ...), and a time-series for position and orientation (if applicable).

You could possibly implement it as a scripting function, but it will be a bit time-consuming and tedious to cover all the cases.

It might be added as a built-in function in the future (e.g. Dymola 2019) - you can get that started with a detailed request to support/reseller.